# In Kittens Game, when does refining catnip to wood get a huge boost in late-game?

Tags: kittens-game

I'm trying to figure out what's causing my refine ratio to go way up (like 9 times its previous rate) in late game. I just saw it happen, but i have no idea why. I didn't buy any upgrades. I did buy the piscine mission, but i was watching to see if the ratio went up after i bought it and it didn't.

One minute i could trade in 5000 catnip for something like 110 wood, and the next minute i got 990 for the same 5000 catnip. I'm late game (pre-chronophysics but i have all the other science and upgrades).

So what is it that boosts it so much around this stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Early on, the Catnip Enrichment workshop upgrade helps with refining into wood, but I'm guessing that isn't it.  Late game, the only thing I can think of is that Bio Labs give Refine Ratio, did you build several of those recently?

Comment: Ohhh yes i did! That must be it. I tend to not build those until i need more science, cause they use up titnaium

Comment: that would do it, then :D they don't give much, but it adds up.  Bio labs are the only reason past the early game you should ever run out of catnip - not only can they consume it for oil, but they make turning it into wood more profitable as well :D